# API YouTube V3 - Buscar vídeos pelo título

Tags: .net, youtube-api

Olá.

Estou utilizando a API do youtube V3 para buscar vídeos em um projeto .net. Acontece que eu tenho o título exato e preciso pesquisar por ele.
Na documentação não está claro se é possível fazer a pesquisa pelo título.
[Documentação da API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Hoje eu tenho a data aproximada, então utilizo as propriedades `PublishedAfter` e `PublishedBefore`, depois percorro a lista de resultados para procurar o vídeo com o título que preciso. Gostaria de otimizar a minha consulta, já que eu possuo o título do vídeo.

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que já possui a API Key e esta habilitada, em resumo:

```
var query = 'mutant giant spider dog'
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
   gapi.client.setApiKey('[SUA_CHAVE_API]');

   var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: query,
        maxResults: 1
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
       $.each(response.items, function(i, item) {
          var idVideo = item['id']['videoId'];
          var urlVideo = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + idVideo;
          //FAZ O QUE QUISER COM OS DADOS. title, description,..
       });
    });
});
```

Setei o maxResults para 1 para trazer o vídeo mais relevante com base no nome, então se passar o nome completo deve ser o primeiro da lista. Mas caso queira iterar pela lista aumente o maxResult como no jsfiddler abaixo.

Teste neste Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/rodrigorf/2ta48oc9/

Obs: lembre de carregar o [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) e [API Google](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad)

============================================================

A consulta via C# é bem parecida também:

```
YoutubeService youtube = new YoutubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    ApiKey = credentials.ApiKey
});

SearchResource.ListRequest listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
listRequest.Q = CommandLine.RequestUserInput<string>("Search term: ");
listRequest.Order = SearchResource.Order.Relevance;

SearchListResponse searchResponse = listRequest.Fetch();
foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResponse.Items)
{
   //USE OS RESULTADOS COMO DESEJAR
}
```

Exemplo completo: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Download lib: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3